# "cv2.imdecode(numpyArray, cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR)" returns None

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, ros

I'm trying to convert an image into Opencv (into numpy array) and use the array to publish the message over a ROS node. I tried doing the same through the following code

```
    fig.canvas.draw()
    nparr = np.fromstring ( fig.canvas.tostring_argb(), np.uint8 )
    print nparr
    img_np = cv2.imdecode(nparr, cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR)
    print img_np
    image_message = bridge.cv2_to_imgmsg(img_np, encoding="passthrough")
    pub.publish(image_message)
```

But, when I tried doing this I get an error message

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

So, I tried printing the values of both the numpy array whose values were `[255 191 191 ..., 191 191 191]`. And what i didn't understand is `img_np` value was `None`. I don't know where I went wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide a [mre] please?

Answer (score 2):

I have encountered similar problems recently.

The `np.fromstring()` method returns an **1-D** `np.array` from the parameter string, regardless of the original resource. To use the `np.array` as an image array in OpenCV, you may need to reshape it according to the image width and height.

Try this:

```
img_str = np.fromstring ( fig.canvas.tostring_argb(), np.uint8 )
ncols, nrows = fig.canvas.get_width_height()
nparr = np.fromstring(img_str, dtype=np.uint8).reshape(nrows, ncols, 3)
img_np = cv2.imdecode(nparr, cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR)
```