# Wrong colours with cv2.imdecode (python opencv)

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, python

I try to display the image located here: http://skyservice.pha.jhu.edu/DR12/ImgCutout/getjpeg.aspx?ra=118.70299999999999&dec=45.721000000000004&width=10&height=10&scale=0.6

The image looks like this:

[image]

I use this code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import urllib
import cv2

url = 'http://skyservice.pha.jhu.edu/DR12/ImgCutout/getjpeg.aspx?ra=118.70299999999999&dec=45.721000000000004&width=10&height=10&scale=0.6'

def url_to_image(url):
    resp = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    image = np.asarray(bytearray(resp.read()), dtype="uint8")
    image = cv2.imdecode(image, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    return image

img = url_to_image(url)
plt.imshow(img)
```

And it displays this:

[image]

Where all colours are too blue. I have tried various possibilities to change `cv2.IMREAD_COLOR` with   values found in the manual, on StackOverflow or elsewhere on the net, like -1, 0, 1, `cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB`, ... but I haven't been able to get the right colours. I have tried `cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY`, it didn't even show in gray scales. I even tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26611536/cv2-imdecodenumpyarray-cv2-cv-load-image-color-returns-none), but `cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR`doesn't seem to exist anymore...

Is there a correct value of `cv2.imdecode()` flag, or a special colormap of plt.imshow(), which would give me the initial colours?

Comment: `matplotlib` requires RGB ordering whereas OpenCV (perversely) uses `BGR`. I think you need to use `cv2.cvtColor()` to convert between the two.

Comment: Great!!! I wasn't aware of that! Cheers mate. it works. I post a reply thanks to your answer right now. :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Thanks to Mark Setchell, it now works. I quote him:

> `matplotlib` requires `RGB` ordering whereas OpenCV (perversely) uses `BGR`

Therefore, the correct code is

```
def url_to_image(url):
    resp = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    image = np.asarray(bytearray(resp.read()), dtype="uint8")
    imageBGR = cv2.imdecode(image, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    imageRGB = cv2.cvtColor(imageBGR , cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    return image
```

Comment: Interesting! I guess this just affect displaying, if I train a model use `BGR`, there will be no difference, right?

Comment: I suppose not. But if you want to display it properly using OpenCV, be careful with colour coding. :)

Comment: @Vimos If you train a network with RGB images and give it a BGR then you can definitely expect worse accuracy. Same if you do the opposite (train with BGR images and give it an RGB image).